# Fill A Graphic With Text Using RectangleF and DrawString

Tags: c#, image, text, font-size, graphic

I've been asked to generate placeholder graphics for some items in a database but with one caveat - the font size needs to be dynamic so that the text fills the entire graphic.

The first iteration of the code works just fine, but the client wants to the font to be bigger so that the graphics are easier to read. Here's a snippet of the part which generates the text:

```
using (Graphics Graphic = Graphics.FromImage(Img))
{
   // Add Some Padding
   Width = Width - 20;
   Height = Height - 20;

   // Generate The Text
   Font GraphicFont = new Font("Arial", 26, FontStyle.Bold);
   RectangleF RectF = new RectangleF(10, 10, (float)Width, (float)Height);
   StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
   sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
   sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
   Graphic.DrawString(Title, GraphicFont, Brushes.Black, RectF, sf);
}
```

Is there I can detect text overflow in my `RectangleF`, or can I detect the size of my `DrawString` before I apply it to the graphic, or is there some other magic I can do to get the text to fill the graphic?

I would like the text to wordwrap and the font to be the same size for all the words, so it doesn't necessarily need to fill the graphic entirely - hope this all makes sense.

Comment: You'll need to test several preselected font sizes and pick one that fits the rectangle.  Go from, say, 8 points to 24 points in increments of 2.  Do avoid using binary search, it isn't stable.  And use TextRenderer when output goes to the screen instead of a printer.

Comment: Thanks for the advise; if I did it your suggested way, how would I know if the text was overflowing the specified rectangle?

Comment: Start with a rectangle that has the desired width and a very large height.  It doesn't fit when the rectangle you get back has too large a height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Graphics.MeasureString` (documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx)

If you want to size text to fill a region, you can do binary search on different sizes to determine the largest size that still fits in your target region, then use that size to actually draw the string.

Comment: Be nice to get some sample code that the OP was likely to have used after accepting this answer